# umount: /dev/sdb1: mount point not specified

Tags: linux, bash, unmounting

if I run:

```
$ sudo umount /dev/sdb1
```

it works just fine. If the label of the storage devide is `red`, I'm trying to bypass learning where it's mounted by (script called `removedrive`):

```
#!/bin/bash

storage=$(pydf | grep $1 | awk '{ print $1 }')
echo $storage
sudo umount "$storage"
```

Running:

```
$ removedrive red
```

Gives me:

```
/dev/sdb1
umount: /dev/sdb1: no se ha especificado punto de montaje.
```

I think it's translated as in the title of this question.

So, what I'm doing wrong?

#### References

- https://blog.programster.org/centos-7-install-pydf
- https://github.com/k4rtik/pydf

Comment: What's the system's locale? `echo $LANG` - https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/locale.

Comment: plz, share `fstab` and `pydf` results.

Comment: Is it possible you are trying to umount it more than one time?

Comment: You do know you can unmount by mounted path too? For example `umount /media/red`

Comment: no, i didn't. that's just great!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to unmount by label. Invoke umount directly instead of writing a script:

```
sudo umount /dev/disk/by-label/$label
```